# What does .<space><command> mean in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

When trying to run a script file. What i saw was

When running `./a_script` this will look for the script in the current directory. Will run it only if execute permission is given.

When running `.a_script` it will search for the hidden script file in `$PATH` and run if found.

When running `a_script` it will search for the script in `$PATH` and run if found.

When running `. a_script` this will search for the script and run it even if execute permission is not given to the script. Why so?

Also, `.a_script` and `./a_script` runs the command in the current shell.

`. a_script` runs it is a different shell?

I may be wrong. Can anybody explain regarding this issue?

The link that i had referred: 
https://ss64.com/bash/source.html

Comment: A period `.` is shell builtin command synonym of `source`

Comment: You have it backwards `.<script>` and `./<script>` runs the command in a subshell (a separate process) `.<space><script>` sources the file into the current shell. See [Is there a difference between “.” and “source” in bash, after all?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182012/is-there-a-difference-between-and-source-in-bash-after-all)

Comment: In case you hear the term around, some folks say things like *"... then dot in your functions"* when they have a script full of helper functions, like a shell library. The old System V startup scripts used to *"dot in common functions"* all over the place.

Answer (score 3):

> When running `./a_script` this will look for the script in the current directory. Will run it only if execute permission is given.
>
> When running `.a_script` it will search for the hidden script file in `$PATH` and run if found.
>
> When running `a_script` it will search for the script in `$PATH` and run if found.

Yes. Note that the "script" need not be an actual shell script in these cases; any executable will do.

Also, `.` is just part of the name of the command here. In `./a_script` it represents the current directory. This works in any path: Try e.g. `ls /./home/.` (same as `ls /home`).

In `a_script` and `.a_script`, the command name doesn't contain `/`, so a `PATH` search is performed. `.` isn't special here.

> When running `. a_script` this will search for the script and run it even if execute permission is not given to the script. Why so?

Because in that case the command is `.` and `a_script` is just an argument to the `.` command. `.` will search for the given file and execute the commands in it (in the current shell). `a_script` cannot be a general executable; it must be a shell script.

> Also, `.a_script` and `./a_script` runs the command in the current shell.

No, if they are indeed shell scripts, they will spawn a new shell to run them.

> `. a_script` runs it is a different shell?

No, it's the opposite: the built-in `.` command specifically runs commands from a file in the current shell (as if you had typed them).

Another name for `.` is `source`, which works the same way, but is easier to search for. See also https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning in your answer that `.` is a synonym for `source`. The later being a bit easier to search for.